# How do I access validates_format_of in Activerecord::Validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to use validates_format_of getting a nomethod error. I think it's because I'm using "class [nameofclass] < ActiveRecord::Validator" and Validator lacks this method.

I need to include something or use another inherit and I don't know how to do this.

codesource: https://github.com/sidhene/WebsiteOne/commit/7621a89300134f3899537ab5f35c2fa33d723b61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validates_format_of` does not work this way , it is meant to create hooks on the database record and run validations before the database record is saved. It does not work as a method on an instance of a class.

What you could do is instead use the regular expression you created and add that to your conditional:

```
validation_regex = %r{\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$}i
if record.image_url.present?
  unless is_whitelisted?(record.image_url) ||
      validation_regex.match(record.image_url?)
    record.errors[:image_url] = 'Invalid image url. Image provider not found in provider whitelist.'
  end
end
```